# No me aparecen los bordes en bootstrap

Tags: html, bootstrap, xml, xslt

Tengo el siguiente código xslt, pero no me genera ningun border-bottom. He probado tanto con una clase creada en el propio documento, como poniendo el border en diferentes sitios, etc. Tampoco me funciona si uso el "list-group-item-primary" por ejemplo, o cualquier similar.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<html xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xsl:version="1.0">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.5.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-B4dIYHKNBt8Bc12p+WXckhzcICo0wtJAoU8YZTY5qE0Id1GSseTk6S+L3BlXeVIU" crossorigin="anonymous"/>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="//192.168.1.101/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/downloadcardsjs.js"></script>
</head>
<style>


  .card-header {
    text-align: center;
  }
  .scroll-padre {
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  .scroll-box {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    height: 200px;
    padding: 1rem;
    margin-right: -50px; /* maximum width of scrollbar */
    padding-right: 50px; /* maximum width of scrollbar */
  }
  .padding{
    padding: 20px;
  }

</style>
<body>
  <!--change to 3 download 1 row-->
  <div class="row">
    <xsl:for-each select="downloads/download">
    <div class=".col-sm padding">
      <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
        <div class="card-header scroll">
          <h6 class="card-title"><xsl:value-of select="@category"/></h6>
          <form class="form-inline">
            <input id="{@did}" class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Buscar" aria-label="Search"/>
          </form>
        </div>
        <div class="scroll-padre">
          <div class="scroll-box">
            <div class="list-group">
              <xsl:for-each select="file">
                <div class="list-group-item border-bottom">
                  <div class="d-inline d-flex justify-content-between">
                    <div class="{@id}">
                      <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
                    </div>

                    <div class="{@id}">
                        <a href="{linkdropbox}" target="_blank">
                          <i class="fas fa-cloud-download-alt fa-lg"></i>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              </xsl:for-each>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</xsl:for-each>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Cualquier ayuda se agradecería.
Adjunto imagen del resultado actual. Lo que busco es que haya un borde o separación entre cada archivo, para que se vea mas claro.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: comprueba mediante "inspeccionar" (f12) que en el div donde tienes puesto el border-bottom no esté tu borde bloqueado por otra clase css. Si lo está, tendrás que crear una clase css y poner el atributo !important detrás de tu border-bottom en tu hoja de estilos

Comment: Hola! Eso ya lo probé, y aun así, no me funciona. Paso a probar las otras respuestas y comento! Gracias :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esta es la clase a la cual tienes que afectar:

```
 .list-group-item:first-child {
    border: none !important;
 }
```

Esto lo puedes agregar a tu código.

En tu código estas generando el border-bottom,  pero lo que no estas haciendo es quitar primero el borde del div.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias! Ha funcionado a la perfección, soy nuevo con bootstrap y ya no sabía cual podría ser el problema